# How canI join a table with itself for a query in a PHP script, and tell the script which column to pick from which table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry if the title is confusing, but I will explain.
I have a database in PhpMyAdmin, and I am trying to do a query on one table joined with itself, where I extract pairs of Company names, for the companies which have the same supplier, with no duplicates.
My tables are:

```
Suppliers(id_sup, sup_name)
Companies(id_co, co_name)
Objects(id_obj, obj_name)
Deliveries(id_sup, id_co, id_obj)
```

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.co_name, cc.co_name
        FROM Deliveries d 
            INNER JOIN Companies c ON d.id_co = c.id_co, 
                                Deliveries dd 
            INNER JOIN Companies cc ON dd.id_co = cc.id_co

        WHERE d.id_obj = dd.id_obj 
        AND d.id_sup = dd.id_sup 
        AND d.id_co < dd.id_co;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border = '1'; align ='center'><tr><th>Company name</th><th>Company name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["co_name"]."</td><td>".$row["co_name"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

This is the essential part of the code. When I print out the results though, PHP only from data returned from "c.co_name" on both columns. In SQL it is easy to tell him that it's actually 2 tables, cause i use alias. But how can I do it in php script when I try to return the results. This part exactly:

```
echo "<table border = '1'; align ='center'><tr><th>Company name</th><th>Company name</th></tr>";
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, and PHPMyAdmin doesn't support SQL Server. What are you *actually* using?

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. I am using Mysql and PhpMyAdmin, through Xampp.

Comment: `echo "<table border = '1'; align` ? Why the `;` its not needed and may do harm

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't know that. But also, any ideas on how to put a table alias, though? :)

Comment: I think you have syntax errors in there so... To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: You should to use column name aliases:
SELECT DISTINCT c.co_name AS name1, cc.co_name AS name2

Answer (score 0):

You actually have table aliases (**c** and **cc**). So you need aliases for your attributes. I mean something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.co_name as nameA, cc.co_name as nameB
        FROM Deliveries d 
            INNER JOIN Companies c ON d.id_co = c.id_co, 
                                Deliveries dd 
            INNER JOIN Companies cc ON dd.id_co = cc.id_co

        WHERE d.id_obj = dd.id_obj 
        AND d.id_sup = dd.id_sup 
        AND d.id_co < dd.id_co";
```

Later use your echo line like this:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["nameA"]."</td><td>".$row["nameB"]."</td></tr>";
```

Hope it helps you...